# Is there a list of possible IllegalAnnotationExceptions I can reference?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have been tasked with taking an existing object structure and converting it into XML I am new to JAXB and am hoping to use it. However, when I try to marshall the data, the following exception if thrown, "3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions"

There used to be 20 + exceptions. However, I was able to research and figure out what practices were not being followed that were causing the errors. However, I cannot seem to find these lased three errors. Is there a list somewhere of possible causes of this exception? I would show the code, however, these errors could be across 22 classes.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is the error below. The code is executed from a command line runner, so please refer the the "Caused by:" exception. There really is a gratuitous amount of code to comb through and it would not be practical to post here. That is why I am asking for a reference list of possible triggers for this exception. Does such a list exist?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at com.xdome.XdomeApplication.main(XdomeApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:489) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:319) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1170) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:441) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.xdome.XMLGenerator.run(XMLGenerator.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Comment: please share the code and error

Answer (score 0):

After working on this issue, I thought I would come bask and leave a few quick thoughts. Unfortunately, it looks like this is a general error. From what I can tell there is no collective list of errors for this exceptions because this is meant to be a catch-all exception when all else fails. However, here are a few item I came across when working on my project:

When working with JAXB, be sure all desired classes that you hope to marshall have a default, empty argument constructor. I assume JAXB just needs to do some basic POJO operations and without a no args constructor, it wouldn't be possible.

```
public class A {

    public A(){}

}
```

Another issue I came across involved inheritance. Many of the previous objects were inheriting from an abstract class that contained common fields. This abstract class was not directly part of the XML hierarchy, however. The inclusion of the abstract class as a superclass seemed to throw the IllegalAnnotationsException. So, where class B is part of the XML structure, DO NOT do the following:

```
public abstract class A {
    ...
}


public class B extends A {

}
```

And finally, the IllegalAnnotationsException can be thrown for misusing JAXB annotation. When getting the aforementioned exception, double check to make sure you are annotating the intended fields and classes. As I am new to JAXB myself, I came across this issues. You can find JAXB documentation on Oracle's website: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/xml/jaxb/index.html

I hope this information helps at least a couple people. At the very least it's one last stack overflow question without an answer.